# Select all HTML ID's as a jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible with jQuery to select all "IDS" of a specific block at the same time? I know that you can specify for example `$('div')` but I would like to select the ID's in my object. Is there an easy way to do this in jQuery? Something like:

```
$object = $('.wrapper');

$object.find(function(){

//GET ALL THE IDS..somehow?! 

});
```

Comment: you want to get a list of all of the `id` values of every element contained within `.wrapper`?

Comment: While it's very straightforward to get all the IDs in an element or in the page, I'm more concerned as to why you think you need them. What purpose does having the IDs of these elements serve? This sounds like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes it was @zzzzBov, once I posted, I looked again and worked out that the problem I was trying to figure it wasn't that at all, and all that was needed was a little bit of logical application. But I have now learned to use `.map()` so thank you @Cory.

Comment: @meeb0: it's an extremely useful function. As is `$.grep()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a little curious of its purpose, but you could try this:

```
var ids = $('[id]', $object).map(function() {
    return this.id;
});
```

It uses `$object` to provide the context for your selector, finds all elements within said context that *have* an `id` attribute, and then builds an array of the `id` values.

FYI, the resulting `ids` variable is a jQuery array-like object. If you just want a plain JS array, add a `.get()` after the map function:

```
var ids = $('[id]', $object).map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
// ^
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHBpa/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$object.find('[id]').each(function(){
  //this.id is your man
});
```